# smallest and largest of the inputs

Tags: java, max, minimum

I was assigned to write a program that read a sequence of integer inputs and print
-the smallest and largest of the inputs
-and the number of even and odd inputs

I figured out the first part but am stumped on how I can get my program to display the largest and the smallest. This is my code so far. How can I get it to display the smallest input aswell?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
      Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter inputs (This program calculates the largest input):");

      double largest = a.nextDouble();
      while (a.hasNextDouble())
      { 
          double input = a.nextDouble();
          if (input > largest)
          {
              largest = input;
          }
      }


      System.out.println(largest);
}
```

Comment: You simply need two tracking variables (`largest` and `smallest`), and two comparisons inside your loop.

Comment: Please consider formatting your code samples "neatly". Especially when they involve several levels of nesting it's hard to read them without indentation.

Comment: Take a look at `Math.min` and `Math.max` to help compare the values and allow for auto assignment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution would be use something like `Math.min` and `Math.max`

```
double largest = a.nextDouble();
double smallest = largest;
while (a.hasNextDouble()) {
    double input = a.nextDouble();
    largest = Math.max(largest, input);
    smallest = Math.min(smallest, input);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double largest = a.nextDouble();
double smallest = largest;
while (a.hasNextDouble()) {
    double input = a.nextDouble();
    if (input > largest) {
        largest = input;
    }
    if (input < smallest) {
        smallest = input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the smallest value in the same manner.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter inputs (This program calculates the largest and smallest input):");

    double firstInput = a.nextDouble();
    double largest = firstInput;
    double smallest = firstInput;
    while (a.hasNextDouble())
    { 
        double input = a.nextDouble();
        if (input > largest)
        {
            largest = input;
        }
        if (input < smallest)
        {
            smallest = input;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Largest: " + largest);
    System.out.println("Smallest: " + smallest);
    }
}
```