# Finding the smallest AND largest number in a list of numbers inputted by the user

Tags: java

i needed help displaying the average, smallest and highest number inputted by the user, but i can only display the average and largest numbers. there is another question like this on here but it wasn't exactly solved, giving the smallest number only. if there is a different way other than Math.min and Math.max, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProblemSet3_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat();

    int snum = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int add = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    int largest = 0;
    int smallest = 0; 


    System.out.print("How much students are in your class?" + '\n');
    snum = input.nextInt(); 


    for (int i = 1; i <= snum; i++) {
        System.out.print("How tall is student #" + i + "?" + '\n');
        height = input.nextInt();

        add += height;
        avg = add / i;

        if (height > largest) {
            largest = height;
        }

    }
    System.out.print("The average height is " + avg + ", while the tallest is " + largest + " , and the shortest is " + smallest +  ".");

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you do a google search on this?

Comment: @GBlodgett yup i tried everything so i just decided to ask the question myself

Comment: You’re already getting the largest, how would you get the smallest in the same way?

Comment: Are you expecting numbers smaller than 0?

Comment: Second answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328779/smallest-and-largest-of-the-inputs

Comment: Have you heard about Integer.MAX_VALUE (or was it Integer.MAXINT)?

Comment: If you want to get Fancy Lookup `PriorityQueue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can just add a simple if/else if statement

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProblemSet3_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat();

        int snum = 0;
        int height = 0;
        int add = 0;
        double avg = 0;
        int largest = 0;
        int smallest = 0; 


        System.out.print("How much students are in your class?" + '\n');
        snum = input.nextInt(); 


        for (int i = 1; i <= snum; i++) {
            System.out.print("How tall is student #" + i + "?" + '\n');
            height = input.nextInt();

            add += height;
            avg = add / i;
            if(i == 1) {
                smallest = height;
            }
            else if(height < smallest){
                smallest = height;
            }
            if (height > largest) {
                largest = height;
            }

        }
        System.out.print("The average height is " + avg + ", while the tallest is " + largest + " , and the shortest is " + smallest +  ".");

    }
}
```

Comment: THIS WORKED THANK YOU :) but what difference did it make when you did if, else if , if instead of if, else if, else if?

Comment: If you do if, else if, else if, initially it will set largest to height if and only if i is greater than 1 first of all, so if you only enter 1 age, the largest height will be 0 while the smallest height may be larger than the largest height because it got set to height. a fix to that might be the answer below mine, where largest is set to height along with smallest when i is equal to 1.

Comment: If you want to skip the `if (i == 1)` statement, you could set `smallest` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 3):

Yes there's a very simple method using streams:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.generate(input::nextInt).limit(snum)
    .summaryStatistics();
```

The `stats` object now holds average, count, max, min, sum.

Edit: sorry just realised you want a prompt message as well:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, snum).map(i -> {
    System.out.println("How tall is student " + i + "?");
    return input.nextInt();}).summaryStatistics();
```

Comment: Right answer, but maybe for a different lesson :-)

Comment: @KevinAnderson well OP did ask if there's a different way!

Answer (score 1):

inside for loop, do:

```
if(i==1){
smallest= height;
largest=height;
}
else {
 if(height< smallest)
   smallest = height
 if(height>largest)
     largest = height
}
```